# How to make an OLE heterogeneous join between MS Access Db and Pervasive SQL 2000i Db

Tags: c#, sql, heterogeneous

I would like to use an OleDbDataReader and a select statement similar to below:

I am using C# 4.0 and .NET 4.0:
Database1 = MS access
Database2 = Pervasive SQL 2000i

```
SELECT db1.Field1, db2.Field2
FROM Database1 db1
INNER JOIN Database2 db2
ON db1.key = db2.key
```

EDIT 1:
If this helps...

Here is the Pervasive Connection String:

```
var constrP1 = "Provider=PervasiveOLEDB;Connect Timeout=60;Data Source=" + PervasiveDBName + ";";
```

Here is the MS Access Connection:

```
var conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + sDataSource + ";User Id=admin;Password=");
```

Comment: you might be able to use linked servers, see SSMS for setting that up.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use LINQ to Objects to join the two resultsets in memory.

Comment: Can I not add the connection string to the database path inside a query somehow like so:  cmd.CommandText = @"select count(t1.key) from [C:\Database1.mdb].[Table1] as t1, [C:\Database1.mdb].[Table1] t2 where t1.key=t2.key";

Comment: @John Saunders.  How would I go about doing that? Any good links?  The two tables are very lage so would this LINQ method avoid looping through both tables like the DataRelation / DataSet method would below?

Comment: Just the standard LINQ syntax for a join. Nothing special.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I just saw that this is MS-Access. Use a linked table from MS-Access to the Pervasive DB via ODBC.  So open the MS-Access DB, create the linked table, [create a ODBC connection on your machine if one doesn't already exist], query the MS-Access Database which will do the heterogeneous magic for you.

Comment: Thanks I would like to do it programatically through code.  I was looking around on the 'net and saw the idea of adding both connections to a DataSet and then add a DataRelation between the tables.  Is that the best way or not?

Comment: Best is subjective.  You'll be reading the entirety of each table and looping through each one. This will use a lot of memory and not be too fast, but if the respective tables are small, it might not be an issue.

Comment: So it sounds like the ODBC connection method is faster than the LINQ to Objects method to join the two resultsets in memory from John Saunders then?

Comment: You'd have to try all three to know for sure as far as the performance characteristics. The rule of thumb is that db engines do better joining than client side collection manipulation.  Since Linq to Objects and DataSets are both will hold all data in memory, I'd expect them to have similar performance and memory usage characteristics. Linked tables is MS-Access will give MS-Access the opportunity to pick a query plan that minimizes memory usage and rows read, depending on what indexes exist, the specifics of the exact query, etc.

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately when I do an MS-Access 2007 external table link to the Pervasive ODBC data source the ODBC call fails.  I do see the field names and data grid is full of "#Name? values.  I will have to probably do what I was doing, namely loop through one dataset and compare to a dictionary list to exclude certain rows from my processing...

Comment: Yup, if functioning ODBC drivers don't exist, that limits your options.